# How to integrate when the reference variable as well as the upper limit both are a fucntion of x?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$\int_{0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} 2^{x} dx$=

I really don't understand how to integrate this. One might see that $2^{\{ x \}}$ is a periodic function with period 1 and the resulting answer would be $\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{ln2}$ But I am confused a bit. Since x is variable, $\lfloor x \rfloor$  will also vary accordingly. So, this won't yield a fixed answer unless we limit the function to $(i,i+1)$, $i$ being and integer. I am really confused. Can we really integrate an expression whose upper limit is a function of x and the variable with respect to which we are integrating is x. Please help me clear my confusion.

Comment: If I saw that notation I'd interpret it as a sloppy way to say what should instead be denoted $\int_0^{\lfloor x\rfloor} 2^u\,{\rm d}u$.

Comment: alright. so the syntax in my question really doesn't hold any meaning does it?

Comment: @Eraserhead No. As written it's meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as coiso said,it is most likely a sloppy way to write $$I=\int_0^{\lfloor x\rfloor}2^tdt$$
in that case,since $$\frac{d}{db}\left(a^b\right)=\ln(b)a^b$$
therefore
$$I=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\left.2^t  \right\rvert_0^{\lfloor x\rfloor}=\frac{2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}-1}{\ln(2)}$$